# Как запросить данные у пользователя в telegram боте (например имя, фамилию) и сохранить в переменную , чтобы потом использовать в других хэндлерах?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Недавно начал изучать создание телеграм ботов с использованием библиотеки aiogram. И по-началу казалось все понятно, когда бот работает по шаблону: если пользователь написал это - сделать вот это. Но я совершенно не понимаю как можно реализовать шаблон вопроса или запроса и сохранения данных.

Буду от всей души благодарен человеку , который пришлет код бота с использованием aiogram, который:
1.запрашивает имя,
сохраняет имя ,
2.запрашивает фамилию ,
сохраняет фамилию,
3.может по команде вывести пользователю введенные им данные(его фамилию и имя)

Comment: Каждый пользователь обладает своим уникальным `user_id` который хранится в `message` объекте, можно создать хранилище (бд или тупо лист, последнее не рекомендуется) и записывать туда поле `user_id`, `имя` и `фамилию` пользователя, а далее проверять наличие записи по тому же `user_id` написавшего боту

Comment: Создайте глобальную переменную листа, вызывайте её, пишите, читайте

Comment: нюанс будет заключаться в том, что при использовании листа, при каждом перезапуске скрипта, данные из листа будут сбрасываться, поэтому всё же лучше позаботиться и создать что-то БДшное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для временного хранения данных вы можете использовать временную память машины состояний, про которую подробно растолкует человек в этой статье: https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/chapter3.html

Пример кода для вашего понимания:

```
from asyncio import Lock

from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.dispatcher.storage import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram import types

bot = Bot(token="<ВАШ_ТОКЕН>", parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

lock = Lock()

# класс для настройки машины состояний
class RegisterMessages(StatesGroup):
    step1 = State()
    step2 = State()


class DB:
    answer_data = {}


@dp.message_handler(commands='start', state=None)
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await RegisterMessages.step1.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Здравствуйте! Введите имя:')


@dp.message_handler(content_types='text', state=RegisterMessages.step1)
async def reg_step1(message: types.Message):
    async with lock:
        DB.answer_data['name'] = message.text
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Принято! Введите фамилию:')
    await RegisterMessages.next()


@dp.message_handler(content_types='text', state=RegisterMessages.step2)
async def reg_step2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with lock:
        DB.answer_data['surname'] = message.text
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Принято! Чтобы посмотреть данные введите команду /check')
    await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(commands='check')
async def get_reg_data(message: types.Message):
    answer = ''
    answer += f'Имя: {DB.answer_data["name"]}\n\n'
    answer += f'Фамилия: {DB.answer_data["surname"]}'
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=answer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp, skip_updates=True)
```

В идеале для средних-крупных проектов использовать API с бэкендом или хотя бы БД.
В данном коде я использую временную память в виде класса и словаря.

Его так же можно сравнить с тем способом, который предоставляет нам FSMContext.proxy(), который позволяет хранит в себе данные разделяя доступ между пользователями, чтобы никто не перехватил данные другого пользователя. Этот способ подходит, если данные мы передаем во время работы машины состояний.

Но так как данные должны быть выведены после закрытия машины состояний. Мы имитировали блокировку данных для передачи между пользователями и создания путаницы с помощью класса Lock() из библиотеки asyncio.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Принцип я понял. Не ожидал если честно на свой глуповатый вопрос такого развернутого ответа.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Просто, когда я только начинал, мне были нужны полные ответы.

Comment: Сейчас я начал разбираться с предложенным вами кодом, и понял насколько на самом деле много он для меня открыл! Я думаю для того чтобы разобраться со всеми этими мелочами в интернете у меня ушла бы уйма времени. И я ,кстати ,осознал насколько много я еще не понимаю. Например, не могли бы объяснить, какую функцию в данном коде выполняет метод set():               await RegisterMessages.step1.set() (первый хэндлер)А еще ,насколько я понял, библиотека Lock в дальнейшем будет очень полезна. Есть ли какой-нибудь ресурс , на котором можно найти информацию по ней ,понятную для новичка ?

Comment: Конкретных ресурсов, где все-все описывают я пока не нашел. Надо читать все по чуть-чуть и строить логику работы. Вам поможет больше практики. Но есть ресурс, где я в принципе научился писать первых ботов: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNi5HdK6QEmX1OpHj0wvf8Z28NYoV5sBJ

Comment: @Андрей. await RegisterMessages.step1.set() запускает машину состояний, устанавливая первое состояние state=RegisterMessages.step1 в другом хенделере. То есть мы просто перенаправляем пользователя на другой хендлер, где указано первое состояние. Надеюсь, я понятно объяснил